# Android Log HERE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Sometimes my application spams the Log output.  This happens when I'm running BLE and accelerometer services.

I've verified that my application is not emitting these logs (we wrote our own log class as a lazy way of turning off logs for production).  Any ideas where this could be coming from, or how I can get to the bottom of what is emitting these logs?  I'm stumped.

Here's an example of the log outputs.

```
09-07 18:02:51.746 3765-3765/com.myapp D/HERE: 584.64/485.0//587.08/481.1018
09-07 18:02:51.747 3765-3765/com.myapp D/HERE: 587.08/481.1018//589.52/481.1018
09-07 18:02:51.747 3765-3765/com.myapp D/HERE: 589.52/481.1018//591.96/481.1018
09-07 18:02:51.747 3765-3765/com.myapp D/HERE: 591.96/481.1018//594.4/481.1018
09-07 18:02:51.747 3765-3765/com.myapp D/HERE: 594.4/481.1018//596.84/481.1018
09-07 18:02:51.747 3765-3765/com.myapp D/HERE: 596.84/481.1018//599.28/481.1018
09-07 18:02:51.747 3765-3765/com.myapp D/HERE: 599.28/481.1018//601.72/481.1018
```

Comment: Is "com.myapp" your application package name?

Comment: yes! (not literally, but my specific package name, yes)  which is why it gives me the creeps

Comment: Put same log which you received in app

Comment: the above is the same log... the only thing i changed is my package name...

Comment: "HERE" word already comes from your code?

Comment: indeed. it's odd.